# Automated testing for Flash/Flex application

Tags: flash-builder, automated-tests

I have to do Automated testing of Application based on Flash builder, after searching on this topic i came to know that flash builder includes Testing API's, and these API's supports HP QTP so After Including Testing API's in my application and making test cases Scripts based on VB scripts I can do automated testing, how should i do automated testing of application based on Flash builder.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at Flex Mojos, which is a Maven Plugin. You can use it for automated builds and tests as well.

Comment: [link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7ec5.html)

Comment: please check the above link, i found this in adobe site.